# How to stop Laravel from malforming its services.json file when receiving multiple requests?

Tags: php, json, laravel

Every time Laravel receives an HTTP requests it seems to be writing a new version of its `app/storage/meta/services.json` file.

When Laravel receives two requests at the same time it often results in the services.json file becoming malformed. My assumption is that the file is opened and written to by two processes at the same time.

Laravel will then throw a 500 with the error:

```
array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array
```

This is particularly troublesome when a single page request might have multiple AJAX calls at once.

I have tried making the file unwritable but this results in Laravel throwing a 500 with a "Permission denied" error. It seems inefficient for Laravel to have to write to this file on every request, surely it should only have to create this manifest when any service providers are changed?

Is there some configuration option I'm missing to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I read a forum post recently about this issue.

The suggested fix was

> Remove the services.json file and re-run composer.

You can review the thread here for more suggestions
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/getting-weird-error-in-laravel/?page=2

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this, the solution was to simply run the artisan command

```
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: I wonder if you might write a sentence or two about why this fixes the problem you've encountered?